# Android App Webview code available to end users

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a webview based hybrid app on IOS and Android. I am testing using TestFlight for IOS and Public Beta testing on Android.

For IOS testers cannot use Safari Developer Tools to view the code, but for Android testers can view the code using Chrome Developer Tools.

How can I prevent the access to the code by Android testers. Is it some setting that I have missed in Android Studio?

Comment: in android webview source code is placed in assets mean end user can extract and can view source in prodution app also.You can't prevent users from accessing webview code.

Comment: for javascipt code you can minify but thats also not 100% secure

Comment: how come Apple manage this and Android allow even release builds to be examined and actually what I am more worried about having their data modified whilst running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it helps to read the manuals and in particular

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html

I had WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled (true); in my code which was causing the problem.